# Spring Security for RESTful API

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I'm building a restful API using Spring 4.1.6 and `spring-boot-starter-data-rest`.

To make the rest api fully functional I need the last piece of the puzzle: security. Now I noticed spring has it's own `spring-security-*` packages that can aid with that task.

I tried using `spring-security-config` and `spring-security-web` and it works like a charm, with the exception that if the user is not authenticated, spring will redirect the user to login, thus giving a HTML login form.
Because it's a Restful API, I just need an error to be returned in a JSON object if the user lacks the credentials or does not have enough permissions to read a particular resource.
I'm sure I'm not the first to ask this question and searched all over the web for people asking the same thing, but couldn't quite find was I was looking for. So.. should I continue my research in this direction with spring-security, or should I find something?

Any advice is welcome,
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the Login Form response to a custom Http Response you need to configure a custom http response handler for Http Security config. If you are using xml for your security configuration use the configuration shown below, `failureHandler` used is the one available in Spring Security package. Update the URL to match yours.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- Rest authentication entry point configuration -->
    <http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" />
        <sec:form-login authentication-failure-handler-ref="myFailureHandler" />

        <logout />
    </http>

    <!-- Using default failure handler -->
    <beans:bean id="myFailureHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: ok, thanks. I'm new to Spring, where do I store this file? also a few documentation links explaining what's happening here would be very helpful.

Comment: Generally you would put this file in src/main/resources. If you are starting out with Spring, follow this link to get up and running https://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2014/06/27/spring-security-on-rest-api/. If you want to use Java Configuration then follow this http://java.dzone.com/articles/secure-rest-services-using